# Value rounded to closest 1 in PHP calculation

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a PHP code that uses data from my database and gives me a value. The code works great but there is decminal issues where it rounds it to the closest 1

This is my Input Values in time format

Input 1  09:21:00
Input 2  09:51:00
Value should be 00:30:00
But it gives me a value of 0

Here is my code

```
<? echo $rows['at_base'] - $rows['disp_time']; ?>
```

If I change value of input 2 to 10:00:00 then it gives me 1

If I can get a value similar to this 00:30:00 would be great or even value 1.3

```
<tr>
                <td align="center"><? echo $rows['disp_time']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $rows['on_scene']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $rows['leave_scene']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $rows['at_base']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $rows['at_base'] - $rows['disp_time']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $rows['close_km'] - $rows['open_km']; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: please explain better the code. I am not able to understand your problem

Comment: @GiacomoM I am trying to get the difference in time between the two values inputted in the database, but the formula rounds the output to closes 1 value, I need hours and minutes difference

Comment: You can use Carbon for that

Comment: You cannot subtract values in the time format, you can only subtract numerical values.

Comment: you could use DateTime Class in PHP or get timestamp and calculate on your own
https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php

Comment: @GiacomoM thanks Carbon should do it never knew about it do you have possible suggested code as I am not sure where to get the echo'd information into my code I have updated the Table code above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do mathematical operations on strings (even if they are formatted as time). You need to work with the proper datatype, which here can be using DateTime objects (or timestamps by using procedural `date()` with `strtotime()`).

```php
<?php 
$start = new DateTime($rows['disp_time']);
$end = new DateTime($rows['at_base']);
$diff = $start->diff($end);
echo $diff->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/236Y9

Or using procedural `strtotime()` and `date()`,

```php
<?php 
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime($rows['disp_time']) - strtotime($rows['at_base']));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/8cJQM

Comment: <? echo date("H:i:s", $rows['disp_time'] - $rows['at_base']); ?> I am using this and getting 01:59:59 reply?

Comment: Please check again, I missed something in the actual answer (its working in the demo though).

Answer (score 1):

You can use date function like this

```
$time1 = new DateTime('09:21:00');
$time2 = new DateTime('09:51:00');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%S');
```

this will gives you "00:30:00" which is your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The Simple Solution is

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // if you set utc, we get exact difference b/w times

$start = strtotime($rows['at_base']);
$end  = strtotime($rows['disp_time']);
$diff =  abs($end-$start);
echo date('H:i:s',$diff);
```